# Modx revo getfilters и getproducts

Tags: modx, revo

На сайте есть 2 контекста "web" и "sale" в одном 3 категории в другом одна.

При расширенном поиске не видит категорию из контекста "sale".
Как сделать чтобы он стал его видеть?

```
<div class="part_select">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="part">Раздел</label>
        <select name="part" id="part" class="form-control input-sm">
            <option value="2">Выберите раздел</option>
            [[getProducts?
                &parents=`2`
                &depth=`1`
                &tpl=`select_option`
                &where=`{"isfolder":1,"parent:<>":2}`
            ]]
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Вывод фильтров -->
<div id="filter_block">
    [[!getFilters?  &tvIds=`2,15,17,32,34,53,54` ]]
</div>
```

Как видно тут используется getproducts и чанк getfilters

думаю что вся проблема в getproducts, как заставить его работать на два контекста?

UPD. А что если я создам ресурс с таким названием в одном контексте, можно ли как то сделать так чтобы он брал данные с другого контекста(именно ресурс)?

Answer (score 1):

http://modx-shopkeeper.ru/documentation/modx-revolution/snippet-getproducts.html

есть опция - context

Я ее никогда не переключал, но мне что-то подсказывает, что можно только один контекст использовать в каждый конкретный момент.

Если это так, то поставь просто 2 вызова [[getProducts]],которые отличаются параметром с контекстом.

Comment: да помоему только 1 контекст можно, я пытался писать web,sale тогда ваще не работало, а если два вызова ставить то они же будут работать как 2 поиска? у меня места нехватит на второй поиск)

Comment: А что если я создам ресурс с таким названием в одном контексте, можно ли как то сделать так чтобы он брал данные с другого контекста(именно ресурс)?

Comment: Вот, почитай про симлинки в модиксе, может поможет.
http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/symlink/using-resource-symlinks

Comment: создал ресурс как символическая ссылка, указал ID, нажал просмотреть, ничего нету